# Abrir link externo automáticamente, con parámetros (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy tratando de montar una SPA, que al entrar en la aplicación, lo primero que tiene que hacer es abrir a una url externa, para la validación OAUTH2.

Es una apertura de url con parámetros.

En toda la información que veo lo redirecciona con

`window.location.href = 'https://web.com';`

¿No hay una manera más "elegante" de hacer con Typescript o el propio Angular? sobre todo para el tema de pasarle parámetros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lo que es el manejo de parámetros puedes usar el [API de URL y URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL_API#url_api_interfaces) para generar o procesar una URL:

```js
let url= new URL('https://web.com/login');
url.searchParams.set('usr','user@null.com');
url.searchParams.set('frm','https://my.com');
console.log(url.href);
```

Una vez generada con los parámetros que necesitas, puedes asignarla directamente.

Comment: Correcto y super sencillo, desconocía esa manera de agregar parámetros. Muchas gracias!